# How can I make my program still run after running once

Tags: java

I wrote a program which interferes with the user. However it only works once. I want my program to run until the user writes "q" or "Q". So far I wrote this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class isbn {
    public static boolean validISBN(String isbnNumber) {
        isbnNumber = isbnNumber.replace("-", "").trim();
        if (isbnNumber.length() == 10 && isbnNumber.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
                if (isbnNumber.charAt(9) == 'X' && i == 1) {
                    sum += i * 10;
                } else {
                    sum += i * Character.getNumericValue(isbnNumber.charAt(10 - i));
                }
            }
            if (sum % 11 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input ISBN Number: ");
        String isbnNumber = keyboard.next();
        validISBN(isbnNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a loop which check if the user enter "q" or "Q"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class isbn {

    public static boolean validISBN(String isbnNumber) {
        isbnNumber = isbnNumber.replace("-", "").trim();
        if (isbnNumber.length() == 10 && isbnNumber.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
                if (isbnNumber.charAt(9) == 'X' && i == 1) {
                    sum += i * 10;
                } else {
                    sum += i * Character.getNumericValue(isbnNumber.charAt(10 - i));
                }
            }
            if (sum % 11 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String isbnNumber;
        do {
            System.out.print("Input ISBN Number: ");
            isbnNumber = keyboard.next();
            validISBN(isbnNumber);
            if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(isbnNumber)) {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an infinite loop and every time check for the input. If the input is q or Q, then break the loop.

```
String input = null;
while(true) {
  input = keyboard.next();
  if("q".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) break;
  validISBN(isbnNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others answers have said you need to use a loop that will wait for user input. You can do this by using [java.util.Scanner#hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) method and evaluate it in a `while` loop.

Here is a snippet from Javadoc:

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input

And here is the actual implementation:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static final Scanner READER = new Scanner(System.in);

public static boolean validISBN(String isbnNumber) {

    isbnNumber = isbnNumber.replace("-", "").trim();
    if (isbnNumber.length() == 10 && isbnNumber.matches("[0-9]+"))
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            if (isbnNumber.charAt(9) == 'X' && i == 1) {
                sum += i * 10;
            } else {
                sum += i * Character.getNumericValue(isbnNumber.charAt(10 - i));
            }
        }
        return sum % 11 == 0;
    }
    return false;
}

public static String getISBN() {

    System.out.println("Input ISBN number: ");
    while (READER.hasNext())
    {
        String input = READER.next();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            System.out.println("Exiting application...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (validISBN(input)) {
            System.out.println("Your ISBN has been accepted.");
            return input;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid ISBN number, please try again: ");
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No more tokes in user input stream");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String isbn = getISBN();
}
```

}